# iOS add certificates from .mobileconfig to keychain

Tags: ios8, network-programming, vpn

I have VPN .mobileconfig file with certificates onto it. I want to apply this configuration with new NetworkExtension framework, so I need to programmatically install (and trust?) this certificates. I can`t get how I can apply this certificates.

Comment: To start with you can check this blog http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/.  But still i am not able to get it done

Comment: Let me know if you get it working..